# Detect if device is iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, browser, browser-feature-detection

I'm wondering if it's possible to detect whether a browser is running on iOS, similar to how you can feature detect with Modernizr (although this is obviously device detection rather than feature detection).

Normally I would favour feature detection instead, but I need to find out whether a device is iOS because of the way they handle videos as per this question [YouTube API not working with iPad / iPhone / non-Flash device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972726/youtube-api-not-working-with-ipad-iphone-non-flash-device)

Comment: See [What is the iOS 5 user-agent string?][1] (duplicate?).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825873/what-is-the-ios-5-user-agent-string

Comment: Is this client-side or server-side detection?

Comment: Hey @DouglasGreenshields, it is client-side

Comment: Also, not a duplicate, I'm asking how to do it. I've never used user-agent sniffing before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877924/what-is-the-list-of-possible-values-for-navigator-platform-as-of-today

Answer (score 1084, accepted):

## Detecting iOS

With [iOS 13 iPad both User agent and platform strings are changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765958/how-to-detect-ipad-and-ipad-os-version-in-ios-13-and-up) and [differentiating between iPad and MacOS seems possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56578799/tell-ipados-from-macos-on-the-web), so all answers below needs to take that into account now.

This might be the shortest alternative that also covers iOS 13:

```
function iOS() {
  return [
    'iPad Simulator',
    'iPhone Simulator',
    'iPod Simulator',
    'iPad',
    'iPhone',
    'iPod'
  ].includes(navigator.platform)
  // iPad on iOS 13 detection
  || (navigator.userAgent.includes("Mac") && "ontouchend" in document)
}
```

`iOS` will be either `true` or `false`

### Worse option: User agent sniffing

User Agent sniffing is more dangerous and problems appear often.

**On iPad iOS 13, the user agent is identical with that of a MacOS 13 computer**, but if you ignore iPads this might work still for a while:

```
var iOS = !window.MSStream && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent); // fails on iPad iOS 13
```

The `!window.MSStream` is to not incorrectly detect IE11, see [here](http://www.neowin.net/news/ie11-fakes-user-agent-to-fool-gmail-in-windows-phone-81-gdr1-update) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx).

**Note:** Both `navigator.userAgent` and `navigator.platform` can be faked by the user or a browser extension.

Browser extensions to change userAgent or platform exist because websites use too heavy-handed detection and often disable some features even if the user's browser would otherwise be able to use that feature.

To de-escalate this conflict with users it's recommended to detect specifically for each case the exact features that your website needs. Then when the user gets a browser with the needed feature it will already work without additional code changes.

## Detecting iOS version

The most common way of detecting the iOS version is by [parsing it from the User Agent string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11129615/1029952). But there is also **feature <strike>detection</strike> inference**[*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios/9039885#comment12752366_9039885);

We know for a fact that `history API` was introduced in *iOS4* - `matchMedia API` in *iOS5* - `webAudio API` in *iOS6* - `WebSpeech API` in *iOS7* and so on.

**Note:** The following code is not reliable and will break if any of these HTML5 features is deprecated in a newer iOS version. You have been warned!

```
function iOSversion() {

  if (iOS) { // <-- Use the one here above
    if (window.indexedDB) { return 'iOS 8 and up'; }
    if (window.SpeechSynthesisUtterance) { return 'iOS 7'; }
    if (window.webkitAudioContext) { return 'iOS 6'; }
    if (window.matchMedia) { return 'iOS 5'; }
    if (window.history && 'pushState' in window.history) { return 'iOS 4'; }
    return 'iOS 3 or earlier';
  }

  return 'Not an iOS device';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre - this code seems simpler though, I just wonder whether I can just specify 'iOS' rather than having to type out all the separate iDevices.... if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
   (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||
   (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
   // Do something
  }

Comment: As far as i know there aren't any properties that include the word *iOS*. I however simplified the regex *(but still, device names are needed)*.

Comment: navigator.appVersion is the browser version not the iOS version! http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_appversion.asp

Comment: `document.write("Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion)` It's the browser version and not the iOS version.

Comment: What you're doing in the second snippet is feature inference, not feature detection. Feature detection is testing features that you're actually going to use, whereas what you're doing is testing features that you happen to know were introduced in a particular version of the OS and inferring the OS version from them. This is fragile because future versions of iOS could remove these features.

Comment: @Pierre also parsing iOS ins't all safe, the older versions of iOS >4 was refered as iPhoneOS including on the iPad

Comment: ..interestingly, just across a userAgent string like `Tiphone T67/1.0 Browser/wap2.0 Sync/SyncClient1.1 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1` ..

Comment: This is a better way to write your check: `var iOS = /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent);`

Comment: Just a note - the navigator.platform array doesn't work on the iPad Simulator because it has the entire phrase "iPad Simulator" in the platform string.

Comment: Testing for iPad, iPhone or iPod in the user agent string will give a false positive in case the user has a Window Phone. Internet Explorer on this device contains a message  '...like iPhone OS...' in the user agent string and thus will return true on this test.

Comment: This is much better 
`var iOS = /(iP*)/g.test(navigator.userAgent);`

Comment: Why aren't you a fan of User Agent sniffing?

Comment: Simplest answer:  var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);

Comment: Is there a way to infer iOS 9 yet?

Comment: @Dzh well in theory you can. It looks like iOS 9 will support forceTouch events.. If so, then you can try and test `'webkitmouseforcechanged' in document;`.. I don't have access to it yet, so if you are able to test this code let me know to update my answer.

Comment: @Pierre good idea, but I wonder whether that will only detect iPhone 6S (as I would expect force touch events will only be available on the devices that support them)?

Comment: @Pierre your code is superb (truely; respect) and I rolled it into some other `detection` code i've been using in prod, resulting in a great/lightweight gist for modern UI/UX control - **isMobile, isTablet, isIE, isIOS**  -https://gist.github.com/gdibble/df3fd4016e632344336f3227a6f159e6

Comment: On a Mac mini I have this string (maybe is helpful for someone that needs to upgrade the regex): ```navigator.userAgent
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"```

Comment: var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream; - this might not work when minifying your js. 

Use this instead - var iOS = new RegExp("/iPad|iPhone|iPod/").test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;

Comment: @Pierre @Dan `navigator.platform` is not deprecated, it's just not recommended to rely on it.

Comment: You are not checking whether it's an iOS device, but whether the device is either an iPhone, iPod or an iPad. If a new device with iOS were to be created, or if an Apple device is running another OS, then this will obviously not work. It's like detecting Windows by checking if the device is Microsoft Surface.

Comment: From iOS 13 the iPad's user agent has changed to "Mac OS", for example:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0 Safari/605.1.15` so this answer need to be updated

Comment: Not working for iOS 13. navigator.userAgent returns value of indexOf("ipad") as -1;

Comment: platform not deprecated (no red border) and less messy than userAgent. You can use `navigator.platform.indexOf('iP')>=0` or `navigator.userAgent.indexOf("(iP")>=0` which seemed to cover 99% of cases (googled useragent and platform strings). And nobody develops to be compatible with 100% of all browsers anyway.

Comment: @paul-rumkin Your last edit makes it NOT work for iOS 13 iPads. Please see the links right above what you edited.

Comment: @PaulRumkin thanks, but there were more necessary fixes in my rejected edit. Please at least fix this inconsistency: `function iOS()` (from someone elses edit)
 but then follows `iOS will be either true or false` (from original author). Also, the edit that changed from var to function forgot to change the text above the edit from `the shortest alternative` to something like  `the most easy to read and edit`

Comment: Finally, this bit `if (iOS) { // <-- Use the one here above` feels a bit off in general. It is supposed to reuse whatever is your final decision on the topmost recommended approach. I think var is better than function for the topmost. Or reformat to allow it to run, emit a boolean, and garbage collect itself. And same applies to the lowermost function - no need to rerun it, so no need to have it as a function.

Comment: @gcharita The edit you rejected yesterday was to fix two glaring bugs in the answer. Please can you fix the bug instead? I've tried and gotten rejected. Otherwise I can try hunting down the original author on social media perhaps. I just want this to be not wrong.

Comment: This bit `(navigator.userAgent.includes("Mac") && "ontouchend" in document)` as recommended both here and elsewhere on StackOverflow page is no longer enough, since  it returns true on Chrome 85 on a non touch device. Tacking on `&& navigator.maxTouchPoints > 2` seems like a good enough stop-gap fix for now.

Comment: `navigator.platform` is now deprecated, so I'm searching for the replacement technique to no avail. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform

Comment: yes navigator.platform is deprecated, yet still supported by all relevant browsers and its replacement "navigator.userAgentData.platform" is useless because in most browsers it returns just empty string or it is undefined as of 1st November 2021

Comment: @Pierre any replacement for `navigator.platform` ?

Comment: This might be a good backwards compatible way to get the platform. `const platform = navigator.userAgentData?.platform || navigator.platform;`

Comment: In IPadOS 16 (maybe earlier) there is a setting (Settings -> Safari -> Request Desktop Website) when enabled it removes any device name like 'IPad' or 'IPhone' from the useragent. Could be the reason for an indentical useragent like a Mac ones. @zvi

Answer (score 70):

After iOS 13 you should detect iOS devices like this, since iPad will not be detected as iOS devices by old ways (due to new "desktop" options, enabled by default):

```
let isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform)
|| (navigator.platform === 'MacIntel' && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1)
```

The first condition for iOS < 13 or iPhone or iPad with disabled Desktop mode, the second condition for iPadOS 13 in the default configuration, since it position itself like Macintosh Intel, but actually is the only Macintosh with multi-touch.

Rather a hack than a real solution, but work reliably for me

**P.S.** As being said earlier, you probably should add IE checkup

```
let isIOS = (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform) ||
(navigator.platform === 'MacIntel' && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1)) &&
!window.MSStream
```

Comment: Why not use the `navigator.userAgent` for this check `/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform)`? It seems that `navigator.platform` always returns 'MacIntel' for iPhone iOS <= 12

Comment: @CharisTheo Because iPad is not in the userAgent in iOS >= 13

Comment: but you are already checking for iPad iOS >= 13 in the second check or am I missing something?

Comment: `navigator.maxTouchPoints` isn't supported in iOS, so that check isn't going to do anything for you.

Comment: @PaulC, You are correct in that maxTouchPoints is undefined for iOS 12 and below, but kikiwora is on the right track since maxTouchPoints is supported in iOS 13. See my answer.

Comment: Curious if there is a similar PHP version of this? Can PHP handle the maxTouchPoints?

Comment: @drooh I know not enough about PHP to be sure, but isn't it used for server-side logic? As far as I know, PHP was never executed in browsers. Thus, it would have no way to detect a page's runtime properties, only those that are passed during requests.
Furthermore, the server should not ever know about the view layer, that's a responsibility of view, in our case - the page itself, not of a server that forms that page.

Again, I may be mistaken about PHP, since I have had very limited experience with it.

Comment: @kikiwora `navigator.platform` is deprecated, any other alternative? 

Answer (score 22):

None of the previous answers here work for all major browsers on all versions of iOS, including iOS 13. Here is a solution that works for Safari, Chrome and Firefox for all iOS versions:

```
var isIOS = (function () {
    var iosQuirkPresent = function () {
        var audio = new Audio();

        audio.volume = 0.5;
        return audio.volume === 1;   // volume cannot be changed from "1" on iOS 12 and below
    };

    var isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var isAppleDevice = navigator.userAgent.includes('Macintosh');
    var isTouchScreen = navigator.maxTouchPoints >= 1;   // true for iOS 13 (and hopefully beyond)

    return isIOS || (isAppleDevice && (isTouchScreen || iosQuirkPresent()));
})();
```

Note that this code snippet was written with priority on readability, not conciseness or performance.

Explanation:

- If the user agent contains any of "iPod|iPhone|iPad" then clearly the device is iOS. Otherwise, continue...
- Any other user agent that does not contain "Macintosh" is not an Apple device and therefore cannot be iOS. Otherwise, it is an Apple device, so continue...
- If `maxTouchPoints` has a value of `1` or greater then the Apple device has a touch screen and therefore must be iOS since there are no Macs with touch screens (kudos to kikiwora for mentioning `maxTouchPoints`). Note that `maxTouchPoints` is `undefined` for iOS 12 and below, so we need a different solution for that scenario...
- iOS 12 and below has a quirk that does not exist in Mac OS. The quirk is that the `volume` property of an `Audio` element cannot be successfully set to any value other than `1`. This is because Apple does not allow volume changes on the `Audio` element for iOS devices, but does for Mac OS. That quirk can be used as the final fallback method for distinguishing an iOS device from a Mac OS device.

Comment: It seems like this will have the side effect of actually changing the audio volume on non-iOS devices (in case that's important to anyone)

Comment: @Tspoon, The provided code snippet creates a throw-away `Audio` element (if necessary). The element is not actually used to play sound in this case, and it does not affect the volume of other `Audio` elements you might employ in your system.

Comment: the volume hack doesn't work - it returns 0.5 and then some thread in webkit resets it back to 1 at some point in the future.

Comment: @Sean, Were you careful to test on an old iPad running iOS 12 or below? I just retested on an old iPad running iOS 12.5.7 (latest version available for that model iPad as of this writing), and confirmed that the Audio element's volume setting still cannot be changed in iOS 12 (I checked the value immediately following the assignment). However, I also noticed that iOS 12 now includes "iPad" in the user agent, so testing for the quirk is now longer needed for old iPads, at least those that are being updated. Either way, the snippet I originally provided continues to work as intended.

Comment: @BobArlof I do have an oldish ipad but it's running 15.7.3
In my tests it momentarily sets the volume to say 0.5 and then about 0.1s later resets it to 1 again. I just did some user agent sniffing to detect it and block our volume controls. I dunno why Apple do these things...!

Answer (score 19):

This sets the variable `_iOSDevice` to **true** or **false**

```
_iOSDevice = !!navigator.platform.match(/iPhone|iPod|iPad/);
```

Comment: what does !! do?

Comment: @astronought double negation is used to cast to a boolean

Comment: @astronought bang bang, you're boolean :D

Comment: Using `/iPhone|iPod|iPad/.test(navigator.platform)` you can avoid the `!!`

Answer (score 11):

UPDATE: My original answer doesn't cover iPad in **desktop mode** (the default changes to desktop mode in <del>upcoming</del> iPadOS 13 and higher).

That's fine for my usecases, if it's not for you, use this update:

```
// iPhone and iPad including iPadOS 13+ regardless of desktop mode settings

iOSiPadOS = /^iP/.test(navigator.platform) ||
           /^Mac/.test(navigator.platform) && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 4;
```

- This should be **safe as long as**

  - desktop Macs don't support touch events at all
  - or not more than 4 touch points (current iOS devices support 5 touch points)
- **It's fast** because the regexp `^` first checks the starting position of the platform string and stops if there is no "iP" (faster than searching the long UA string until the end anyway)
- **It's safer** than `navigator.userAgent` check as `navigator.platform` is much less likely faked
- Detects iPhone / iPad Simulator

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
 Wow, a lot of longish tricky code here. Keep it simple, please!

This one is IMHO fast, save, and working well:

```
 iOS = /^iP/.test(navigator.platform);

  // or, if you prefer it verbose:
 iOS = /^(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/.test(navigator.platform);
```

Comment: ```iOS = /^(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/.test(navigator.platform);```
rather than this i would do 

```iOS = /^(iPhone|iPad|iPod)/.test(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || navigator.platform);``` 
as a fallback measure cuz in my case navigator.platform didn't work, but doing it like later worked fine

Comment: `navigator.platform` didn't work? Are you really on iOS then?. Check with http://jeka.info/test/navigator.html . `userAgent` gives false positives because some vendors fake it to mimic Apple devices for whatever reasons. `vendor` just returns either `Google Inc.`, `Apple Computer, Inc.`, or nothing (in Firefox).

Comment: ⚠ [navigator.platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform) is being discouraged: "[it] should almost always be avoided in favor of feature detection."

Comment: @A-TECH: this is is The Remaining of the "almost always" case. Example (stupid): All iOS devices have Zapf's "Optima" font installed. For some reasons you want to know if that font is available. Please giive me some feature-detecting code for this usecase!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#addtest), you can add a custom test for it.

It doesn't matter which detection mode you decide to use (userAgent, navigator.vendor or navigator.platform), you can always wrap it up for a easier use later.

```js
//Add Modernizr test
Modernizr.addTest('isios', function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g);
});

//usage
if (Modernizr.isios) {
    //this adds ios class to body
    Modernizr.prefixed('ios');
} else {
    //this adds notios class to body
    Modernizr.prefixed('notios');
}
```

Comment: Be carefull, Modernizr automatically lowercase the name of the added test. (in your example, Modernizr.isiOS will never return true). Bad behavior of the lib in my view ...

Comment: Just tiny notice: you can simplify `return x ? true : false` to `return Boolean(x)` or just `return !!x`

Answer (score 8):

A simplified, easy to extend version.

```
var iOS = ['iPad', 'iPhone', 'iPod'].indexOf(navigator.platform) >= 0;
```

Comment: If you also want this to work on iOS Simulator you can use: `navigator.platform.replace(' Simulator', '')`.

Comment: But it doesn't work, cause `['str'].indexOf('string') == -1`

Comment: navigator.platform will be *exactly* 'iPad', 'iPhone' or 'iPod' unless the simulator is running.

Answer (score 6):

## Detecting iOS (both <12, and 13+)

Community wiki, as edit queue says it is full and all other answers are currently outdated or incomplete.

```
const iOS_1to12 = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);

const iOS13_iPad = (navigator.platform === 'MacIntel' && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1));

const iOS1to12quirk = function() {
  var audio = new Audio(); // temporary Audio object
  audio.volume = 0.5; // has no effect on iOS <= 12
  return audio.volume === 1;
};

const isIOS = !window.MSStream && (iOS_1to12 || iOS13_iPad || iOS1to12quirk());
```

Comment: 'platform' is deprecated now

Answer (score 4):

It's probably worth answering that iPads running iOS 13 will have `navigator.platform` set to `MacIntel`, which means you'll need to find another way to detect iPadOS devices.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this a couple years ago but i believe it still works:

```
if(navigator.vendor != null && navigator.vendor.match(/Apple Computer, Inc./) && navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) 

    {

        alert("Ipod or Iphone");

    }

else if (navigator.vendor != null && navigator.vendor.match(/Apple Computer, Inc./) && navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))  

    {

        alert("Ipad");

    }

else if (navigator.vendor != null && navigator.vendor.match(/Apple Computer, Inc./) && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1)

    {

        alert("Safari");

    }

else if (navigator.vendor == null || navigator.vendor != null)

    {

        alert("Not Apple Based Browser");

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Wherever possible when adding Modernizr tests you should add a test for a feature, rather than a device or operating system. There's nothing wrong with adding ten tests all testing for iPhone if that's what it takes. Some things just can't be feature detected.

```
    Modernizr.addTest('inpagevideo', function ()
    {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod)/g) ? false : true;
    });
```

For instance on the iPhone (not the iPad) video cannot be played inline on a webpage, it opens up full screen. So I created a test 'no-inpage-video'

You can then use this in css (Modernizr adds a class `.no-inpagevideo` to the `<html>` tag if the test fails)

```
.no-inpagevideo video.product-video 
{
     display: none;
}
```

This will hide the video on iPhone (what I'm actually doing in this case is showing an alternative image with an onclick to play the video - I just don't want the default video player and play button to show).

Comment: iOS10 now allows for `playsinline` so you can use `'playsInline' in document.createElement('video');` as a test now  https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/2077

Answer (score 2):

If you're using React, There is great library for this kind of issues: **REACT-UGENT**. (Built with ua-parser-js.)

https://github.com/medipass/react-ugent

**Available browsers are:**

chrome, chromium, edge, firefox, ie, lynx, safari, opera

**Available OS are:**

android, blackberry, chromium os, debian, ios, linux, mac os, ubuntu, unix, windows

**Available devices are:**

console, computer, mobile, tablet, smarttv, wearable, embedded

Easy to use as:

```
<Ugent browser="safari" os="ios">
  <div>
    This text only shows on Safari on iOS.
  </div>
</Ugent>
```

If you're not using React, basically, you can use - ua-parser-js

https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js

Answer (score 2):

If you are still trying to check if is iOS or not, I recommend you to use this approach:

1. Create a folder called `helper`
2. Create a file called `platform.ts` or `platform.js`
3. Export the function `isIOS`:

```
export const isIOS = () => {
    let platform = navigator?.userAgent || navigator?.platform || 'unknown'

    return /iPhone|iPod|iPad/.test(platform)
}
```

**The result will be `true` if is an `iPhone` or `iPod` or `Ipad` or it will be `false` otherwise.**

You may ask, why do I need to check `navigator.userAgent || navigator.platform`, well the reason is simple the second option used to be the default one but now it is deprecated and some browsers will stop supporting this in the future, the first one is more reliable.

You can check here about the deprecation that I mentioned above:

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform#:~:text=Deprecated%3A%20This%20feature%20is%20no,be%20kept%20for%20compatibility%20purposes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform#:%7E:text=Deprecated%3A%20This%20feature%20is%20no,be%20kept%20for%20compatibility%20purposes).

### Logging the `userAgentData`, `userAgent` and `platform`.

Using the function below, I received these logs:

```
    console.log({
        userAgentData: navigator?.userAgentData?.platform,
        userAgent: navigator?.userAgent,
        platform: navigator?.platform,
    })

    {
        "userAgentData": "",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
        "platform": "MacIntel"
    }
```

I was testing it on my Macbook and it worked on different browsers and operation systems. So, as you can see `navigator?.userAgentData?.platform` will not work at all.

**I also didn't receive any errors related to my typescript, even though that I am using React to call this function**.

### Bonus, isAndroid

If you wondering how to check if is an Android platform, I suggest you don't follow the idea of doing the opposite of `isIOS` as:

```
const isAndroid = !isIOS();
```

The reason is quite simple, it will not work since desktops will be recognized as an Android platform.
To solve this problem you just need to do this check:

```
export const isAndroid = () => {
    const ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() + navigator?.platform.toLowerCase();
    const isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;

    return isAndroid;
}
```

The reason why we are checking `navigator.userAgent` plus `navigator?.platform` is to support old browsers and the new ones.

Comment: Will it be safe to remove `navigator?.platform` if that is going to be removed in future and only rely on `navigator?.userAgent`?

Comment: Since this will be removed it means the result will be `undefined` but since we also want to target old browsers just in case, it makes sense to add it there.

Answer (score 1):

The user-agents on iOS devices say iPhone or iPad in them.  I just filter based on those keywords.

Comment: There's also iPod Touches to consider.

Comment: @DouglasGreenshields Correct.  Forgot about that one but I believe it transmits its identity in the user-agent, as well.

Comment: User agent of iPad safari will no longer include "iPad" from iPadOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to test `navigator.userAgent` or `navigator.platform`:

```js
const isIOS = typeof navigator.standalone === 'boolean';
```

`navigator.standalone` is only set on iOS Safari. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator#non-standard_properties), [Safari HTML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW3).

Comment: What if the browser is chrome?

Comment: @IBG just tried and it returns "undefined" on iOs chrome. So this answer is not correct

Comment: @IBG I just tried this on Firefox 38.1 on iPhone (iOS 14.3) and Chrome 95.0.4638.50 on iPad (iPadOS 15.0.2) and it worked on both

Comment: @strix25 are you sure you typed the code correctly?

Comment: Using the `const` in @JefferyTo's example above worked well for me with this conditional check: `if (isIOS === true ) { //stuff for iOS } else {// stuff for all other }`

Comment: 'platform' is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Apple Pay JS API checks

`if (window.dw && window.dw.applepay && window.ApplePaySession &&      window.ApplePaySession.canMakePayments()) {

// do the needful

}`

Answer (score 0):

Because `navigator.platform` is deprecated and it is better to not use it anymore, I want to add an other solution.

You can filter on MacOS systems by checking the `navigator.vendor`.
When the outcome is `Apple Computer, Inc.`, you know it is MacOS.

Comment: `navigator.vendor` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/vendor) as well

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to be compliant with PageSpeed Insights and Lighthouse best practices which flags "issues" found in the console for the use of `navigator.userAgent` (etc), this can help you (I gleaned this from Boostrap 5):

```
function getUAString() {
    let uaData = navigator.userAgentData;
    if (null !== uaData && uaData.brands) {
        return uaData.brands.map(item => item.brand + '/' + item.version).join(' ');
    }
    return navigator.userAgent;
}

const isIOS = /iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(getUAString());
```

Answer (score 0):

this was my solution after suffering a lot its not perfect but hope to help someone, I have tried it and it’s and it exactly target iPad safari.

```
function detectSafariOnIpadOS() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
  var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(userAgent);
  var isIpad = /iPad/i.test(userAgent);
  var isMacintosh = /Macintosh/i.test(userAgent);
  var isTouchDevice = "ontouchend" in document;

  console.log("User Agent:", userAgent);
  console.log("detectSafariOnIpadOS result:", isSafari && (isIpad || (isMacintosh && isTouchDevice)));

return isSafari && (isIpad || (isMacintosh && isTouchDevice));
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `includes`

```
  const isApple = ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod', 'iPad Simulator', 'iPhone Simulator', 'iPod Simulator',].includes(navigator.platform)
```

Comment: This misses out on the the "... Simulator" variety. So many answers, so few well-researched :(

Comment: platform is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform

Answer (score -2):

In my case the user agent was not good enought since in the Ipad the user agent was the same as in Mac OS, therefore I had to do a nasty trick:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)");

/**
 * If we are in landscape but the height is bigger than width
 */
if(mql.matches && window.screen.height > window.screen.width) {
    // IOS
} else {
    // Mac OS
}
```

Answer (score -3):

In order to detect the iOS version, one has to destructure the user agent with a Javascript code like this:

```
 var res = navigator.userAgent.match(/; CPU.*OS (\d_\d)/);
    if(res) {
        var strVer = res[res.length-1];
        strVer = strVer.replace("_", ".");
        version = strVer * 1;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

`var isiOSSafari = (navigator.userAgent.match(/like Mac OS X/i)) ? true: false;`

Comment: This ternary operator is useless; `test` returns a boolean and can replace `match`