# How to run jQuery code only if device is iOS based?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect if device is iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)

Here is what I want to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Run This code if device is iOS based
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
            $("body").queryLoader2({
                barColor: "#37201b",
                backgroundColor: "#c2a875",
                percentage: true,
                barHeight: 5,
                completeAnimation: "grow"
            });
       });
        // if it is not iOS run this code
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("body").queryLoader2({
                barColor: "#37201b",
                backgroundColor: "#c2a875",
                percentage: true,
                completeAnimation: "grow",
                barHeight: 5
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Instead of comments what do I write to make it work?

Comment: Better question: WHY do you want it only to run on iOS, and should you be using feature detection instead of OS detection?

Comment: @Blazemonger no no, I only needed part to detect iOS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/i);
    if (agentID) {     
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
            $("body").queryLoader2({
                barColor: "#37201b",
                backgroundColor: "#c2a875",
                percentage: true,
                barHeight: 5,
                completeAnimation: "grow"
            });
       });     
    }
    else
    {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("body").queryLoader2({
                barColor: "#37201b",
                backgroundColor: "#c2a875",
                percentage: true,
                completeAnimation: "grow",
                barHeight: 5
            });
        });
    }
});
```