# How to redirect all iPhones requests to a different URL?

Tags: ios, iphone, regex, nginx, webkit

How can I configure `nginx` to redirect all requests from users who use an iPhone to a different server? Just iPhones. Not the other iOS devises.

I found the following code but I can't figure out how to regex the iPhone requests.

```
set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;

if ($http_user_agent ~* "???????????") {
  set $mobile_rewrite perform;
}

if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
  rewrite ^ http://just_for_iphones.com/ redirect;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios

Comment: I Think this question is better suited on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 1):

```
set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;

if ($http_user_agent ~* "Apple-iPhone") {
  set $mobile_rewrite perform;
}

if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
  rewrite ^ http://just_for_iphones.com/ redirect;
  break;
}
```

Comment: Great you got the answer in just 1 hours.. intelligent... huuu.