# jQuery scrollTop not working inside iframe on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, iframe, scrolltop

iOS and iframes.. such a pain.
I've a simple *back to top* button which should animate the scrolling (instead of just jumping to the top of the page).

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.backtotop', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1500);
});
```

This works everywhere, except for iframes on iOS. I still haven't fully understood how iOS handles iframes. jQuery's .scrollTop() function won't work either (which can't be animated anyway).

The only thing which works in iframes on iOS is this:

```
parent.self.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Obviously not the best solution since this won't work for desktop browsers.
Any deeper knowledge on how to fix this or iframes on iOS in general is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like specificing the context fixes the issue:

```
$('body, html', parent.document).animate({ scrollTop: 0 },1500);
```

Since this will only work for iOS I've included the iOS detect from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios):

```
var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );

$(document).on('click touchstart', '.backtotop', function() {
    if (iOS) {
        $('html, body', parent.document).animate({ scrollTop: $("body").offset().top},1500,"easeOutQuart");
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("body").offset().top},1500,"easeOutQuart");
    }
});
```

Apparently only *parent.document* works as the context. *parent.window* or only *document* have no effect.

Comment: Very good solution! `parent.document` did the trick for me. Thanks

Comment: Does this still work for you? For me, iOS 9.2 on an IPad 3 no result. Copyed your code exactly!

Comment: Works like a charm on iOS12.2