# jQuery add class not working on certain mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a **class** that I add to navbar with **jQuery**. It works perfectly fine on **android phones**, **tablets**, **desktop** but not on **iphones**. I have no clue on what might be the issue. Actually the class is added except the part **background-color**?

Here is the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var vlera = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(vlera > 0){
            $('.navbar').addClass('n-bg');
        }
        else
        {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('n-bg');
        }
     })
```

Comment: Step up to what?

Comment: "*Also [I] want to note that this is the very last time [I] use [jQuery]. Time to step up.*" - this is entirely irrelevant to your question (which is why I removed it). If you log `viera` to the screen in iPhones does it report a value that you expect?

Comment: @DavidThomas well i admit you are right

Comment: @DavidThomas i editet the question a bit. The class is added but not the background color?

Comment: Can you post enough of your code that those of us with iPhones can view what happens? Please: read the [mcve] guidelines for what we'd need to see.

Comment: It seems like iOS have some issues with `jQuery`'s `scrollTop()` function. [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478157/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-inside-iframe-on-ios)