# Dynamic height of main block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

On the page, there are 3 blocks (header, main and footer). 4th (apple_ios_status_bar_background) is hidden by default and displayed (or hidden) dynamically in code. When this unit is not displayed, you can see all 3 blocks on the page. If the display 4th block - the block footer goes down the page. It is necessary that would block main changed its height dynamically (all blocks should always be visible on the page).

Code https://jsfiddle.net/j3qm5qgx/1/

In JS detect iOS system, if true - show `apple_ios_status_bar_background` block, hide if false.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the topic

Comment: @BipBip On the page, there are 3 blocks (`header`, `main` and `footer`). 4th (`apple_ios_status_bar_background`) is hidden by default and displayed (or hidden) dynamically in code. When this unit is not displayed, you can see all 3 blocks on the page. If the display 4th block - the block footer goes down the page. It is necessary that would block main changed its height dynamically (all blocks should always be visible on the page).

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is it about detecting an apple device? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios

Comment: @Bondye No. I detect iOS device and show block `apple_ios_status_bar_background` with `$("#apple_ios_status_bar_background").show()`. After `show()`, `footer` block  beyond the visible area of the page (image 1).

Comment: Use sth like `document.getElementById("apple_ios_status_bar_background").style.display = "";`

Comment: @Elyor use your code, but nothing change. May be this picture helps [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Art/safarimetrics.jpg) - i need all blocks in **Visible area** of Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle you did not include jQuery and second you did not define iOS. If you do so it works as you wanted it to.

```
var iOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3qm5qgx/4/

Note that Safari does not really mean iOS and that you could solve that issue in css with media device.

If you do not want your footer to go offscreen, you could set it on bottom via css:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3qm5qgx/5/

Another way would be to change it by jquery, since main now is 20 pixels more short:

```
if (iOS) {
    $("#apple_ios_status_bar_background").show();
    $('main')[0].style.height = 'calc(100% - (40px + 20px + 20px))';
} else {
    $("#apple_ios_status_bar_background").hide();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j3qm5qgx/6/

Comment: I dropped part of the code does not required, which not related to this issue. Check for iOS works fine, this is no problem. When opened this page with iOS (ex. iPhone) and displayed unit `apple_ios_status_bar_background`, the `footer` at the bottom slides down and it is not visible in the portrait orientation (if you turn in the landscape - the block `apple_ios_status_bar_background` is hidden and then the `footer` is visible).

Comment: Ah alright, I understand. The height is your problem.

Comment: This is what you need when you show the apple only content: $('main')[0].style.height = 'calc(100% - (40px + 20px + 20px))';