# How can I detect whether or not a device uses it's own video player rather than the HTML5 player?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, video

**How can I detect whether the actual HTML5 player is being used, or if a 3rd party player is hi-jacking the video outside of HTML5?**

iPhone doesn't use the HTML5 video player (thanks Apple) but rather uses its own player full-screen. This means any apps, regardless of responsive design, don't work if they expect an interface to be involved with the video.

So I need to know this in order to either make my app work differently with devices that do something similar to iPhone, or at least fail gracefully.

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible, check [this](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1498)

Comment: @David I suppose you should post that as the answer :/

Answer (score 0):

As I told in you in my comment, it seems that [is not possible](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1498).

So I am afraid that you will need to go for agent sniffing. Check this post to see [how to identify an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9038625/5247200).