# How to detect user agent is iPhone using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Thanks advanced !!!
I am very new in this . i want to detect the user agent using regex. here the regex

```
(mobile|Mobile|iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Kindle|NetFront|Silk\-Accelerated|hpwOS|webOS|Fennec|Minimo|Opera Mobi|Opera Mini|Blazer|Dolfin|Dolphin|Skyfire|Zune)
```

how can i detect it was in only iPhone & iPad .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if device is iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)

Comment: Hi Tushar.  
              I have one doubt if i tested with Emulator mean it's working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is very simple to do this. New regexp is

```
(iPhone|iPad)
```

Comment: Hi MystreX
. I have one doubt if i tested with Emulator mean it's working ?

Comment: Yes, sure. (If you use the emulator of iPhone or iPad)

Comment: but i cannot get it MysterX. Can u please provide me the Exact Regex

Comment: your answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios) as was pointed above