# Issue detecting non-mobile device in javascript

Tags: javascript, navigator

I have a script that will detect iPhone/iPad and Android devices, but having trouble singling out Desktop/Laptop devices. When viewing the page on an iPhone/iPad, it triggers an alert for "iDevice" first, then an alert for "Desktop". I need to be able to show a different form, based on what platform the user is viewing the page on (iPhone/iPad, Android, Windows Phone, Desktop/Laptop (non mobile devices)). I'm not trying to target resolution, I'm trying to target PLATFORM.

**HTML**

```
<div class="iDevice">iDevice</div>
<div class="android-view">Android Device</div>
<div class="desktop">Desktop</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $("#email").hide();
$(".desktop").hide();
$(".iDevice").hide();
$(".android-device").hide();
$('#checkbox').change(function () {
    $('#email').slideToggle();
});

if((navigator.platform === 'iPhone') || (navigator.platform === 'iPad')){
alert("iDevice");
    $(".iDevice").show();
    $(".android-view").hide();
    $(".desktop").hide();
}

var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
alert("Android");
    $(".iDevice").hide();
    $(".android-view").show();
    $(".desktop").hide();
}

else if ((navigator.platform != 'iPhone') || (navigator.platform != 'iPad' ) || (isAndroid === false)){
alert("Desktop");
    $(".desktop").show();
    $(".iDevice").hide();
    $(".android-view").hide();
}
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/86e48ebn/)**

Comment: Are you trying to tell a user what phone their using or use specific JavaScript actions for different devices because of functional support?  If the latter, I would say you should do Feature Detection with something like [`has.js`](https://github.com/phiggins42/has.js/) or [`Modernizr`](https://modernizr.com/) instead.  Additionally, hiding and showing large chunks of a page based on device is foolish as well.  You should instead try doing `Responsive Design` using CSS and the like.

Comment: These days, it's really a folly to lump devices into a specific category because there's a full continuum.  Where's the dividing line between a phone and a tablet?  Where's the dividing line between a tablet and a laptop?  There is none.  You can buy a laptop that can be a tablet or you can buy a tablet that can be a laptop.  Instead, look at the capabilities the platform has (screen size, touch, etc...) and adjust your UI based on only that.  They you offer a UI that is usable regardless of what category the device is in.

Comment: And, what makes something non-mobile?  Are you going to somehow detect that the device has no battery or has no wireless because pretty much everything else is mobile in some way these days.

Comment: The solution to my question is much simpler than this, @jfriend00. The idea is that the user will see a different form based on the device they are on. It has nothing to do with conceptual ideas of what makes a device a device. It's simply "if this device is on iOS, show this form", if this device is an Android platform, show this form", and if the user is on a desktop/laptop, show this form". My script is working for iPhone/iPad and Android, but having an issue singling out non android/iOS devices. I tried to say if the device is neither of these, than show this.

Comment: @Matt - but why do you show a different form if it's a laptop vs. a tablet vs. a large phone?  That desire seems folly from the beginning.

Comment: @jfriend00 - The idea is to capture different information based on the device. However, the reason why is irrelevant. It's not a matter of screen size, but device type that is my concern.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific need to show content based **directly** on the device, you should practice `Responsive Design`.  The idea is to style your content for different screen sizes, layouts, or whatever, with `CSS` and, if need be, [`Media Queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).  Additionally, if you need to have your `JavaScript` perform different actions based on API availability, you should use a `Feature Detection` library such as [`has.js`](https://github.com/phiggins42/has.js/) or [`Modernizr`](https://modernizr.com/).

---

That being said though, if you still want to pursue displaying content based on device, one glaring problem that I can see is that your `if` statements are incorrect:

`if (navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || 'iPad'){}` resolves to `'iPad'` which is `truthy`.

You need to use a compound `if` statement like:

```
if ((navigator.platform === 'iPhone') || ((navigator.platform === 'iPad')){}
```

This goes for all of your other `if` statements as well.

Another alternative is to use a `regex.test()` as was done in another question: [Detect if device is iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios).

---

Additionally, trying to navigate the mess that is the `userAgent` string will drive you mad.  Consider reading WebAim's [History of the browser user-agent string](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) in order to see why.  I mean, unless you enjoy manhandling all the different user agent strings that Microsoft Internet Explorer has put out in order to trick servers into thinking that it isn't actually IE.

Comment: I've updated my code, but now the iPhone/iPad are hitting the iDevice then Desktop, as I'm seeing an alert for iDevice then Desktop. http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/86e48ebn/

Comment: @Matt Can you edit your question and include the values for `navigator.platform` and `navigator.userAgent` are for each device you want to target? I don't have access to them all which means helping you debug this is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked my logic, and was able to separate the forms with the following mix of targeting `navigator.platform` and `navigator.userAgent`:

```
$("#email").hide();
$(".iDevice").hide();
$(".android-device").hide();
$('#checkbox').change(function () {
    $('#email').slideToggle();
});

//IF WINDOWS PHONE
if(navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")){
    $(".iDevice").hide();
    $(".android-view").show();
    $(".desktop").hide();
}

//ELSE IF iPhone/iPad
else if((navigator.platform === 'iPhone') || (navigator.platform === 'iPad')){
    $(".iDevice").show();
    $(".android-view").hide();
    $(".desktop").hide();
}

//ELSE IF DESKTOP (NOT iPhone/iPad/Android/Windows Phone)
else if ((!navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")) || (navigator.platform !== 'iPhone' || 'iPad' ) && isAndroid === false){
    $(".desktop").show();
    $(".iDevice").hide();
    $(".android-view").hide();
}

//IF IS ANDROID
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    $(".iDevice").hide();
    $(".android-view").show();
    $(".desktop").hide();
}
```