# CSS hack only for apple iphone

Tags: javascript, css, html, browser-feature-detection

I want to change some CSS property only in the apple iphone devices. Is there any way to find the apply iphone alone.

For all deives

```
.menu{
    -webkit-transition:all 100ms ease;
    -moz-transition:all 100ms ease;
    -o-transition:all 100ms ease;
    transition:  all 100ms ease;
}
```

Only for Apple Iphone

```
.menu{
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if device is iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)

Comment: You can also try http://browserhacks.com/ or https://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There you go:

Simply add those CSS `@media` queries

```css
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

Taken from [Media Queries for Standard Devices - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

And if you are interested in JS query, use:

```
if( /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 document.querySelector('html').classList.add('iphone');
}
```

Then, add the `.iphone .menu {}` rule to your CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) {
    $('html').addClass('iphone');
}
```

```css
.menu {
    background:#8BC34A;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s ease;
    transition:  all 0.3s ease;
}
.menu:hover {
    background:#9C27B0;
}
.iphone .menu{
    transition: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: i would suggest this way as this may help for even furthre use as well so