# JavaScript - one link, all app stores, non-Safari detected

Tags: javascript, android, ios, browser

I'd like to have a single 'Get App' link that auto-detects the user's device type and browser and directs to the appropriate location (iTunes, Google Play, or website sign-up). I am currently using Onelink.to, but it has the following limitations:

- if you're on iOS using a non-Safari browser (like Chrome) you end up looking at a bunch of raw JSON because it doesn't know to launch the App Store app. In this case, I'd prefer to direct to the iTunes website or better yet, deep link into the App Store app.
- if using the link on your own site and a user is on a device that redirects to a different page of your own website, it complicates setting up event-based goals in Google Analytics

Are there any good JavaScript solutions that handle the App Store redirect while excluding this action on browsers that don't support the iTunes headers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript navigator.userAgent and parse it to detect the device. Then just generate the link according to it.

Here is an example for ios detection: 
[Detect if device is iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)