# Why <iframe> with pdf file doesn't show on page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I have a problem. 
When i put

```
 <iframe src="http://laska-podium.ru/rules/rules.pdf" 
        style="width: 100%; height: 600px; margin-top: 5px;" style="position:absolute;" frameborder="0">Your browser doesn't support iframes</iframe>
```

in my modal window it shows only on large screens. But on iPhone it empty.

Comment: it will never work. I believe it won't even work on desktop in any other browser then IE.

Comment: And how to add pdf file on website?

Comment: either download button or convert it to html. Browser is not meant to view pdfs

Comment: simply upload the PDF file in google drive, then you can upload and Embed it anywhere in your website.

Answer (score 0):

iOS is not able to load built-in PDF reader into the modal window.

Add the [Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/712093) to check again iPhone/iPad device and display the direct link to PDF instead (or open PDF in the separate window) then.