# Replace href if user is on iPad / iPhone / iPod

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen a lot of websites about replace in `JavaScript`, I am new to `JavaScript`, I appreciate some help?
This `JavaScript` code didn't work when I tried it in JSFiddle:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone|iPod|iPad') != -1) {
    $("a[href$='iPhone']").attr("href", function() {
      return this.href.replace("iPhone", "IIIphone");
    });
  } else {
    $("a[href$='iPhone']").attr("href", function() {
        return this.href.replace("iPhone", "Android");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my `HTML` is

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com?iPhone-type=iPhone">The 1 link</a>
<a href="http://www.mypage2.com?iPhone-type=iPhone">The 2 link</a>
```

Comment: I didn't fully read, but `.indexOf('iPhone|iPod|iPad')` looks like it will be doing something unintended. Do you maybe want to search for `iPhone` **or** `iPod` **or** `iPad`?

Comment: i mean at all 3  when sombody call the link from iPhone or from iPad or from iPod onley IOS

Comment: just note that `"iPhone".indexOf('iPhone|iPod|iPad') === -1`.

Comment: Then you probably want something like `navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if device is iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)

Comment: ASDFgerta yes  you have right but how to detect the IOS  wenn i dont add   .indexOf('iPhone|iPod|iPad') === -1

Comment: i nead just a simple javascript when sobody call the url in a Iphone to remove in this html the Iphone text and put it IIIphone  and from another devise  to replace Iphone in Android