# Track a redirect page with Google Analytics using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, google-analytics

I have this redirect link, www.example.com/redirect which identifies if the mobile device is iOS or Android, after that it redirects to different links based on the device. I have tried different methods found in this forum but it never worked.

Below is the latest code I've tried:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

      // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"


    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Android";
    }

    // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        return "iOS";
    }

}

    function DetectAndServe(){

if (getMobileOperatingSystem() == "Android") {
     ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'page': '/33red33',
            'hitCallback': function() {
              window.location.href = 'http://android.com';
           }
           });           

    }
if (getMobileOperatingSystem() == "iOS") {

      ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'page': '/33red33',
            'hitCallback': function() {
            window.location.href = 'http://apple.com';
           }
           }); 

    }

};

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be just a typo on here but nowhere in your code are you actually calling the function DetectAndServe, change your code to the below and it should work.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

      // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"


    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Android";
    }

    // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        return "iOS";
    }

}

    function DetectAndServe(){

if (getMobileOperatingSystem() == "Android") {
     ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'page': '/33red33',
            'hitCallback': function() {
              window.location.href = 'http://android.com';
           }
           });           

    }
if (getMobileOperatingSystem() == "iOS") {

      ga('send', 'pageview', {
            'page': '/33red33',
            'hitCallback': function() {
            window.location.href = 'http://apple.com';
           }
           }); 

    }

};
DetectAndServe();
});

</script>
```

Comment: yea i figured it out myself a couple of days ago....cant believe it was something like this, brain lag lol. thanks for your input !