# How to know the device orientation AND direction (landscape 90° or -90° ?)

Tags: html, css, iphone

I'm working on how to best fit the content around the iPhone notch with media-query `orientation` and contstants `safe-area-inset-*`.

It works well to be sure not to hide important UI under the notch, but it also give awkward results in landscape as the "unnotched" side is also concidered having a safe area gap and so unnecessarily pushing the UI to the center.

How can I detect not only the orientation, but also the direction (i.e. is the notch left or right) to apply spacial css on each cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPhoneX and Notch detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226824/iphonex-and-notch-detection)

Comment: I'd rather like a CSS only solution (similar to the media-query `orientation`), but I guess there are none...