# Not able to download PDF in safari browser on iphone or ipad pro ios12

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux, ios12

I have PDF download functionality in my web app. It is working fine with all the browsers and iOS11 but it's not working on safari browser and ios12 on mobile or iod pro. 
I am getting below error - 
**WebKitBlobResource error 1**

```
export const downloadPDF = (downloadLink, fileName, trackId, productId, historyId) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return request.doGetAuth(downloadLink).then(response => {
      let contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (_.includes(contentType, 'application/json')) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        return response.blob();
      }
    }).then(blobby => {
      if (!blobby.message) {
        const blob = new Blob([blobby], {
          type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        if (isIos()) {
          if (!isCriOs()) {
            // For ios 
            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            dispatch(downloadReadyAction(url, fileName));
          } else {
            // if chrome
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
              dispatch(downloadReadyAction(reader.result, fileName));
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          }
        } else {
          FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);
        }
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Problem downloading pdf from server ' + err)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I was confused by the "isIos" function that i thought for a second was a native javascript function...So more information here on how to create your own isIos function : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we open pdf in new url tab , The file doesn't exist but its only cache stored inside the browser. So when we generate the blob and redirect to current tab to point to the generated blob url, We lose the cache.
So opening url in new window helps it.

```
   let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Comment: Still not what I want (embedding the PDF) but thanks a bunch for the workaround!

Comment: I believe if you change the `contentType` to `application/octet-stream` it will download instead of embed.