# How can I use UTF-8 in blob type?

Tags: javascript, blob

I have to export table by csv file.

csv file data is from server by Blob type.

```
Blob {size: 2067, type: "text/csv"}
```

```
async exportDocumentsByCsv() {
    this.commonStore.setLoading(true)
    try {
      const result = await DocumentSearchActions.exportDocumentsByCsv({
        searchOption: this.documentSearchStore.searchOption
      })

      // first
      // const blob = new Blob([result.body], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' })

      // second
      // const blob = new Blob([`\ufeff${result.body}`], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' })
      const blob = result.body
      console.log('result.body', result.body)
      const fileName = `document - search - result.csv`
      if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        // for IE
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName)
      } else {
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName)
      }
      this.commonStore.setLoading(false)
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err.errorMessage)
      this.commonStore.setLoading(false)
    }
  }
```

I have to set utf-8 or else because of my language.

I tried to fix this issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

I searched fix this issue by using `\ufeff` but When I try to use this like 
second way, It doesn't work for me.

```
| [object  | Blob]  |
```

Comment: [How to Convert a javascript object to utf-8 Blob for download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53929108/how-to-convert-a-javascript-object-to-utf-8-blob-for-download)

Comment: @SudhirOjha This is not work for me. Response data from server is type of Blob not object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Blob* doesn't take care of the encoding for you, all it sees is binary data. The only conversion it does is if you pass in an UTF-16 DOMString in the constructor's BlobsList

The best in your situation is to set up everything in your application from server to front as UTF-8 and to ensure that everything is sent using UTF-8. This way, you will be able to directly save the server's response, and it will be in UTF-8.

Now, if you want to convert a text file from a **known encoding** to UTF-8, you can use a [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder), which can decode a ArrayBuffer view of the binary data from a given encoding to DOMString, which can then be used to generate an UTF-8 Blob:

```js
/* const data = await fetch(url)
  .then(resp=>resp.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buf => new Uint8Array(buf));
*/
const data = new Uint8Array([147, 111, 152, 94 ]);
// the original data, with Shift_JIS encoding
const shift_JISBlob = new Blob([data]);
saveAs(shift_JISBlob, "shift_JIS.txt");

// now reencode as UTF-8
const encoding = 'shift_JIS';
const domString = new TextDecoder(encoding).decode(data);

console.log(domString); // here it's in UTF-16


// UTF-16 DOMStrings are converted to UTF-8 in Blob constructor
const utf8Blob = new Blob([domString]);
saveAs(utf8Blob, 'utf8.txt');


function saveAs(blob, name) {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.download = name;
  a.textContent = 'download ' + name;
  document.body.append(a);
}
```

```css
a{display: block;}
```

Comment: `Blob {size: 2067, type: "text/csv"}` This is my fetch result. How can I use this? `result.body.arrayBuffer()` occurs error `result.body.arrayBuffer is not a function`

Comment: You need to make you fetch return an ArrayBuffer instead of a Blob, if you can't, `data = await new Response(result.body).arrayBuffer()` would do, or even [FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer). But note that you **must know** the current encoding to be able to reencode it. Better send directly the correct encoding from your server.

Comment: I can't use new Response constructor.

Comment: Then use FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer, or even simply set up your fetch request so that it returns an ArrayBuffer directly, or even better **set your server so that it returns the file as UTF-8 directly**.

Comment: solve this issue by using `FileReader` and `TextEncoder` thanks!