# Prevent enter action on IOS return click

Tags: javascript, html, ios, vue.js, preventdefault

I have problems with IOS return key on keyboard (in Safari on iphone for example).
I am using vue js in my web application where I have textarea in chat component:

```html
<textarea
        class="field-text__input field-text__input--height-small field-text__input--max-height"
        rows="1"
        ref="messageField"
        placeholder="Your message"
        @keydown.enter.exact.prevent="send"
        @keyup.enter.ctrl.exact="expandTextarea"
        :value="messageText"
        @input="updateMessage">
</textarea>
```

On desktop browser or android devices message is sent on "Enter" click. But on IOS click on "return" key on keyboard also send message. 
How I can prevent this action for IOS "return" key?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create some custom logic inside your `send` function in order to catch and return(quit) the function if you detect that it is an iOS device.

[This stackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/6178832) is a great place for inspiration for sniffing user agens (What the device tells you it is)

Comment: Thanks. I am also thinking about it, but hoped there is another way for prevent.