# I need to hidden plist file on computer

Tags: php, ios, wordpress, plist

I'm Create a WordPress apple store and need to hidden plist file in computer
 I have a site for download plist 
I created the program for ios and webview for my site and just need to be hidden my plist file on computer for not download any people just ios users.

sorry for grammar

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. You want to identify the user's device and decide if to allow download or not? User agent detection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if device is iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)

Comment: Yes, I read this, but I want to get a solution if you're not able to simulate (inspect element mobile view) the browser on the IPhone mode and see the file link.

Comment: That is how HTTP works. There is no guarantee. You can't trust the user, everything can be spoofed. Foolproof approach would be some sort of SAML/SSO with Apple's services.

Comment: Yes, your answer is absolutely correct, but our customer surely insists on hiding this link as it is. You must know what I mean by the customer as this Apple approval file and the certificate is not publicly visible. Some People are reporting for jealousy and hostility, and our client account is blocked by Apple, should be a solution.

Comment: Correct that we are talking about a Wordpress site, not an iOS or macOS app? Maybe I am not understanding something. Good luck.