# Unable to redirect based on device

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to redirect users to different URLs based on their device (android, iOS or Windows) but react router dom blocks any trying to move to any other domain

Please help, code I am using is pasted below

```js
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
  window.location.href = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android&hl=en_US";
} else

  // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
  if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
    window.location.href = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8";
  } else

if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
  window.location.href = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/instagram/9nblggh5l9xt?activetab=pivot:overviewtab";
} else {

  window.location.href = "https://instagram.com";
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's react-router-dom is blocking the redirect? Are there any errors?

Comment: Please check the console log for any error messages