# iFrames use according to user OS

Tags: html, iframe

I want to show one out of two iframe, according to user OS.
if user use iOS it shows one and if androind it show other.

`<iframe id="e8e2c112-f7ce-4d21-96e7-59729619a527" src="https://www.vectary.com/viewer/v1/?model=e8e2c112-f7ce-4d21-96e7-59729619a527" frameborder="0" width="50%" height="480"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

you could detect userAgent in Javascript, like this.

```
<html>

<body>
  <div id="vectary"></div>
  <script>

    function getOs() {
      var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

      if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        //Vectary iframe 1 - for Android
        return '<iframe id="e8e2c112-f7ce-4d21-96e7-59729619a527" src="https://www.vectary.com/viewer/v1/?model=e8e2c112-f7ce-4d21-96e7-59729619a527" frameborder="0" width="50%" height="480"></iframe>';
      }

      // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
      if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        //Vectary iframe 2 - for iOS
        return '<iframe id="e8e2c112-f7ce-4d21-96e7-59729619a527" src="https://www.vectary.com/viewer/v1/?model=e8e2c112-f7ce-4d21-96e7-59729619a527" frameborder="0" width="50%" height="480"></iframe>';
      }

      //Vectary iframe 3 - for all other cases
      return '<iframe id="e8e2c112-f7ce-4d21-96e7-59729619a527" src="https://www.vectary.com/viewer/v1/?model=e8e2c112-f7ce-4d21-96e7-59729619a527" frameborder="0" width="50%" height="480"></iframe>';
    }

    document.getElementById("vectary").innerHTML = getOs();

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```