# Deep Linking With Javascript Not working for Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, deep-linking

I am opening an application if installed or playstore link. It works well in all modern browsers. However what happens in Safari is my application gets opened but also my App Store link gets opened. Can anyone help me to identify the issue?

```js
(function() { 
  var app = {  
    launchApp: function() {
      var operating_system = getMobileOperatingSystem();
      //alert(operating_system);
      if (operating_system == "iOS") {
        //window.location.replace("GiftCast://"); //if app installed
        window.location.replace("App://"); //if app installed
      } else {
        window.location.replace("myapp://mytest/login");
      }
      // window.location.replace("intent://#Intent;action=android.intent.action.SEND,package=com.abcd.asd;end");         
      this.timer = setTimeout(this.openWebApp, 1000);  
    },
    openWebApp: function() {
      var operating_system = getMobileOperatingSystem();
      //alert(operating_system);
      if (operating_system == "iOS")
        window.location.replace("https://itunes.apple.com/app/idss11?mt=8");
      else
        window.location.replace("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appname.Live"); //if app  not installed then play store
        //window.location.replace("myapp://mytest/login");        
    } 
  };
   
  app.launchApp();
  //app. openWebApp();
})();

/**
 * Determine the mobile operating system.
 * This function returns one of 'iOS', 'Android', 'Windows Phone', or 'unknown'.
 *
 * @returns {String}
 */
function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

  // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"
  if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
    return "Windows Phone";
  }

  if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
    return "Android";
  }

  // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
  if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
    return "iOS";
  }

  return "unknown";
}
```

Comment: `this.timer = setTimeout(this.openWebApp, 1000);` would seem to be the culprit, even though it's called after `window.location.replace`. I don't even see why you need it.

Comment: I have written it just because, if app is not installed it will wait and then open the app store link