# How to redirect user to app store iOS 13 if app is not installed

Tags: javascript, ios

I have one button. It has two functionality. It first tries to open my app. If the app doesn't exist, it redirects to the app store for the app. The issue I'm coming across is that in the new OS (iOS 13), this bit of code no longer works.

```
vm.openApp = function () {                
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

var app = {
    launchApp: function () {
        window.location.replace("testappscheme://" + window.location.href);
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.openWebApp, 1000);
    },

    openWebApp: function () {
        // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
        if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
            window.open("https://apps.apple.com/us/app/kw-control-panel/id127991312356", '_blank');
        }

    }
};

app.launchApp();
```

};

May I get some tips on how to get this up and running for the newer iOS