# How to prevent timeout function from executing if app opens ok

Tags: javascript, ios

at the moment I have one button. If the button is clicked, it will open the app if installed, otherwise open the appstore. The issue I'm coming across is on iOS, if the user chooses to open the app, the app opens, followed by the appstore , which then causes the app to minimize.

```
openAppBtn.onclick =

    function () {
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

        var app = {
            launchApp: function () {
                window.location.replace("testappscheme://https://kw-dev.realestate.com" //added closing quotation
                this.timer = setTimeout(this.openWebApp, 1000);
            },

            openWebApp: function () {

                if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
                    window.location.replace("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ca.phoenixsoftware.kwagentprod");
                }

                // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
                if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
                    window.location.replace("https://apps.apple.com/us/app/kw-control-panel/id1279913356");
                }

            }
        };

    app.launchApp();
};
```

May I ask how do I have the appstore not open if the app has opened or have it not minimize the application.

Comment: Are you using [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication)?

Comment: You should use a universal link and have iOS handle opening the App or the App Store for you