# How to use different font for iPhone devices?

Tags: iphone, wordpress, fonts, arabic, elementor

My website's Arabic font letters appears separated from each other which makes it un readable so I want to use a different font that will display only on iPhone & iPad devices in wordpress, I am using Elementor to design the site. Is there's a code or plugin I can use to apply different font for iOS devices?

```
https://ozaro.com/ar/our-history/
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you cant do that just using css. You'll need JavaScript too.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios) is an answer on finding if device is iOS or not.

So basically this is what you'll have to do.

1. Set a unique classname for the parts of your website you need that font to be applied. E.g. "arabicf"
2. Go to your footer builder and drag drop an html widget.
3. Inside the widget write your js between script tags.

P.s. the logic behind the js is simple
If ios then "arabicf" style fontFamily = X.

Comment: Thank you very much Mhdi, appreciate your help