open a app direct from package name using nodejs or php
generate a link which contain package name of the app that will open direct app if it is already  installed on mobile means direct launch app and if it is not installed than option install from play store using nodejs or php
i have try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app but it is redirect to play store if app is installed i want that direct open app if i click on link
i need a link like serveradress/link?package=com.test.app and package name is dynamic currently if i click on link than it is open play store and show open button on play store instead of this i directly open app

Servers or arbitrary web pages can't open applications on the clients. Think about the huge security hole if they could.

but i need to generate link which has package name which is not static and i provide a ;link to client and when client side click link at that time action perform

you're likely looking for Android App Links

Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or an Android problem?

i need to make link for this using any tech nodejs or php or js

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and share your attempts to resolve the problem. PHP usually does not know anything about "package name of the app", neither of any apps that are installed on the devices requesting a website

@NicoHaase i think he has on server that handles an api application that will send and email/sms with a link to the api aplication , and he needs to open somehow the mobile aplication because from email/sms you can not open your mobile application, i had the same problem.

@Full-Stack Developer
i need a link like serveradress/link?package=com.test.app and package name is dynamic currently if i click on link than it is open play store and show open button on play store instead of this i directly open app

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Are you struggling with the PHP part or the JS part?

@NicoHaase have above mention like :  i need a link like serveradress/link?package=com.test.app and package name is dynamic currently if i click on link than it is open play store and show open button on play store instead of this i directly open app and it is not complasury to make nodejs or php it can fine any one

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and share your attempts to resolve the problem

you can read this post
Open android application from a web page
You need a server that will display a simple html page that will look like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
            var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
            if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
                return "android";
            }
            // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
            if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
                return "ios";
            }
            return "unknown";
        }

        function writeLink () {
            var parser = document.createElement('a');
            parser.href = window.location.href;
            var query = parser.search.substring(1);

            var iosURL = "com.mycompany.app://?"+query;
            iosLink.href = iosURL;

            var androidUrl = "intent://home/"+query+"#Intent;scheme=###PROJECTNAME###;package=###PACKAGENAME###;S.browser_fallback_url=?"+query+";end";
            androidLink.href = androidUrl;

            var os = getMobileOperatingSystem();

            if (os=="ios") {
                window.location.href=iosURL;
            } else if (os=="android") {
                window.location.href=androidUrl;
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad=writeLink()>
<a id="iosLink" href="">Open in iOS</a>
<a id="androidLink" href="">Open in Android</a>
</body>
</html>

